# Error Generic detail view must be called with either an object pk or a slug, even with the pk

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to update records of a view which has a foreign key field, due to this I'm getting an error, since I tried to update another model without a foreign key field and it worked very well.

There are other quetions like this, but in my case I'm passing the pk.

**urls.py**

```
 urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^info/(?P<studentpk>\d+)/update/$', views.updatestudent.as_view(), name="updatestudent"),

]
```

**views.py**

```
class updatestudent(UpdateView):
    model = Student
    form_class = forms.studentform
    template_name = "temp/updatestudent.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("courses")
```

**updatestudent.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

**models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    classfk = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birth_date = models.DateField('Birthdate')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**error**

```
AttributeError: Generic detail view updatestudent must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django doesn't expect you to use `studentpk` in the URL pattern. The easiest fix is to use `pk` instead.

```
url(r'^info/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', views.updatestudent.as_view(), name="updatestudent"),
```

If you really want to use `studentpk`, then set [`pk_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg) in the view.

```
class updatestudent(UpdateView):
    model = Student
    form_class = forms.studentform
    template_name = "temp/updatestudent.html"

    pk_url_kwarg = 'studentpk'
```

Note that in Python, the recommended style is to name your class based view `UpdateStudent`, and your form class `StudentForm`.

Comment: It worked :DD, but one more question, i used the ''studentpk'' because i already had used a ?P<pk> for another parameter, even changing ''studentpk'' for ?P<pk> i had problems,  can't there be parameters with the same name ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question in your comment.

Comment: url(r'^info/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<studentpk>\d+)/$
could I repeat it ?
url(r'^info/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$
but they're holding different values.

Comment: No, you can't repeat the group name in a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks, God bless you.